# Mocking a tree data structure

Tags: c#, data-structures, nunit, moq

I'm writing a program that takes a given binary tree and attempts to determine if the tree is balanced.

The program expects a binary tree as an input, for example : 1,-1,-2,-3 would be represented with 1 as a root node and the subsequent.getLeft() (or .getRight() if the tree was balanced differently!) commands would yield -1,-2,-3.

How can I achieve this behaviour given it requires repeated calls to different node objects? Is it best practice to achieve this in moq, or would it be better to just use a plain implementation.

Comment: If you know how many times each method will be called, you could set up the return value for each subsquent invocation of your getLeft() and getRight() methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the plain implementation. I won't recommend you to use fake in this case. the effort to create fake will cost more then just create tree for each scenario you will test. another danger is to create over-specified  test which will failed on any change.

your method will probably implement as follow:

```
    public static bool isBalanced(Node root){

        if(root==null){
            return true; 
        }
        else{
            int lHight = root.left.height();
            int rHight = root.right.height();
            if(Math.Abs(lHight - rHight) > 1)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return isBalance(root.left) && isBalance(root.right);

        }
    }
```

as you can see there is a recursion. usually it's very hard to test recursion methods with fakes. in your situation you can test the method behavior without any fake so i'd say that's is the right choice.

I recommend you to tests the following behaviors:

empty tree, root balance, root is not balance(oriented left, oriented right), many layer tree: balance, oriented right, oriented left

if you'll create the above scenarios you probably cover all situations and your tests won't be over-specified...